# Pandas unstack but only create multi index for certain columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame that is production data for a factory. The factory is organised into lines. The structure of the data is such that one of the columns contains repeating values that properly thought of are headers. I need to reshape the data. So in the following DataFrame the 'Quality' column contains 4 measures, that are then measured for each hour. Clearly this gives us four observations per line.

The goal here is to transpose this data, but such that some of the columns are single index and some are multi index. The row index should remain ['Date', 'ID']. The single index columns should be 'line_no', 'floor', 'buyer' and the multi index columns should be the hourly measures for each of the quality measures.

I know that this is possible because I accidentally stumbled across the way to do it. Basically as my code will show, I put everything in the index except the hourly data and then unstacked the quality column from the index. Then by chance, I tried to reset the index and it created this amazing dataframe where some columns were single index and some multi. Of course its highly impractical to have loads of columns in the index, because we might want to do stuff with them, like change them. My question is how to achieve this type of thing without having to go through this (what I feel is a) workaraound.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID'       : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] * 2,
     'Date'     : ['2013-05-04' for x in xrange(12)] + \
                  ['2013-05-06' for x in xrange(12)],
     'line_no'  : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] * 2,
     'floor'    : [5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5] * 2,
     'buyer'    : ['buyer1', 'buyer1', 'buyer1', 'buyer1',\
                   'buyer2', 'buyer2', 'buyer2', 'buyer2',\
                   'buyer1', 'buyer1', 'buyer1', 'buyer1'] * 2,
     'Quality'  : ['no_checked', 'good', 'alter', 'rejected'] * 6,
     'Hour1'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)],
     'Hour2'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)],
     'Hour3'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)],
     'Hour4'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)],
     'Hour5'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)],
     'Hour6'    : [random.randint(1000, 15000) for x in xrange(24)]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'line_no', 'floor', 'buyer',
                                'Quality', 'Hour1', 'Hour2', 'Hour3', 'Hour4',
                                'Hour5', 'Hour6'])
DF.set_index(['Date', 'ID'])
```

So this is how I achieved what I wanted, but there must be a way to do this without having to go through all these steps. Help please...

```
# Reset the index
DF.reset_index(inplace = True)

# Put everything in the index
DF.set_index(['Date', 'ID', 'line_no', 'floor', 'buyer', 'Quality'], inplace = True)

# Unstack Quality
DFS = DF.unstack('Quality')

#Now this was the accidental workaround - gives exactly the result I want
DFS.reset_index(inplace = True)
DFS.set_index(['Date', 'ID'], inplace = True)
```

All help appreciated. Sorry for the long question, but at least there is some data riiiight!

Answer (score 1):

In general `inplace` operations are not faster and IMHO less readable.

```
In [18]: df.set_index(['Date','ID','Quality']).unstack('Quality'))
Out[18]: 
               line_no  floor   buyer  Hour1                               Hour2                               Hour3                               Hour4                               Hour5                               Hour6                             
Quality                                alter   good  no_checked  rejected  alter   good  no_checked  rejected  alter   good  no_checked  rejected  alter   good  no_checked  rejected  alter   good  no_checked  rejected  alter   good  no_checked  rejected
Date       ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
2013-05-04 1         1      5  buyer1   6920   8681        9317     14631   5739   2112        4211     12026  13577   1855       13884     12710   7250   2540        1948      7116   9874   7302       10961      8251   3070   2793       14293     10895
           2         2      6  buyer2   7943   7501       13725      1648   7178   9670        6278      6888   9969  11766        9968      4722   7242   4049        6704      2225   6546   8688       11513     14550   2140  11941        1142      6683
           3         3      5  buyer1   5155   2449       13648      2183  14184   7309        1185     10454  11742  14102        2242     14297   6185   5554       12505     13312   3062   7426        4421      5693  12342  11622       10431     13375
2013-05-06 1         1      5  buyer1  14563   1343       14419      3350   8526   1185        5244     14777   2238   3640        6717      1109   7777  13136        1732      8681  14454   1059       10606      6942   9349   4524       13931     11799
           2         2      6  buyer2  14837   9524        8453      6074  11516  12356        9651     10650  15000  11374        4690     10914   1857   3231       14627      6590   6503   9268       13108      8581   8448  12013       14175     10783
           3         3      5  buyer1   9032  12959        4613      6793   7918   2827        6027     13002  11771  13370       12767     11080  12624  13269       11740     10543   8609  14709       11921     12484   8670  12706        8001      8991

[6 rows x 27 columns]
```

is a quite reasonable idiom for what you are doing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. When I did this on the real data it gave me alter , good, etc. for the buyer and line etc. as well. How is this different? The result is exactly right, but i don't quite see how it's happened.

Comment: unstack uses the specified level, and leaves the remaining index alone as unstack creates *columns*

Comment: Yes I realise that, but I am trying to get line_no, floor and buyer out of the index, but not as an inner index for alter. Your solution is giving me a column index of (line_no, alter), (line_no, good) etc. which is not quite what i was after. I may be missing something. In my original solution the index is (line_no, ), (buyer, ) - which seems different. But in the data you pasted it appears as I want it, but when I recreate it it is different.

Comment: you may just need to do the steps you are doing, BUT w/o the inplace arg, that just makes it very confusing, no reason to do it that way

Comment: Ok thank you, unstack could do with an option over which existing columns you wish to unstack. Perhaps it makes no difference, but it seems nonsensical to me to have (line_no., alter), (line_no., 'good) etc. as line_no. is constant. What's your beef with inplace? Just out of interest - I'm always keen to write the best possible. R

Comment: issue with ``inplace`` is mainly that you can not pipeline operations, makes code much longer, and esp more confusing (and has no real benefit, virtually all inplace operations are just doing internally on a copy). virtually all pandas operations return copies. a user looking at code will be mystified by inplace calls, they only server to confuse.

Comment: you can give multiple levels to unstack, FYI